# Collection View Cell does not display image in image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a simple gallery for an iOS application. I'm working with a UICollectionView inside of a ViewController. Everything seems to be working fine, but I can't get the image I'm trying to use to display inside of the collection view cell. I will just dump some code here, I have been desperate to find a solution but nothing seems to work.

This is the gallery.m file:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;
{
    //just a random value for testing
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
    //another random test value
    return 5;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"customCell";

    customCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier
                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //UIImage *image = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"skull.png"];

    //I tried all of the below code to get the image to show but nothing seemed to work
    //[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"skull.png"]];
    //[cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    //[cell.imageView reloadInputViews];
    return cell;
}
```

This is the customCell.h file (the UIImageView outlet is connected to the image view inside of the collection view cell):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface customCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

Concerning the connections in the storyboard everything should be fine, also it would be difficult to show here but I will try to explain anyways.
The UICollectionView is connected in the gallery.h file like so:

```
@interface gallery : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;


@end
```

The collection view cell in the storyboard has the custom class "customCell" and identifier "customCell".

If anybody could point me to where my mistake could be it would be awesome!
Thank you!

Comment: Add a breakpoint or log statement in the cellForItem method, and check the value of the image view property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the storyboard, sometimes in cells, xCode set images frame to (0,0,0,0). It made me crazy a lot of times ^^

EDIT : 
To create a custom collection cell, create an empty XIB file.
Add a collectionViewCell in it with all you want.
Make the connections with you .h file.

In your viewController -> viewDidLoad method add

```
[myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"collectionCellXIB" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
customCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input but I checked the storyboard and the values are correct.

Comment: Ok :) Did you check that the name if the image is "skull" and not "Skull"?

Comment: Yes, I already triple checked everything for typos, I'm sitting in front of this since 8 hours now but can't seem to find what's wrong...

Comment: Use cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor to be sure the imageView is displayed.
Did you create the cell in a separate XIB or in the main storyboard?

Comment: Well, it seems the imageView is not displayed at all, no red squares. I will try looking more in that direction maybe I find something. I used the cell that was created by the UICollectionView, that I added to the ViewController in the main storyboard.

Comment: I edited my post to explain you how I create my custom collection cells, it should work ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I have followed your instructions and everything seems to be working now. I will accept your answer as soon as I can ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Have fun :)

Comment: The if (!cell) part is unnecessary. The dequeue methods on collection views always return a cell, as long as you've registered one.

Answer (score 6):

I had this very similar problem. I could not display image view inside uicollection view cell, when storyboard is used. I just removed the following code in ViewDidLoad of CollectionViewController:

```
//[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Now the ImageView is displayed inside cell.