# UiCollectionView not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a simple collectionView and for some reason is not showing at all.
I'm setting the images to some custom cells I made (ProfileCells) through a string list I made (pages). 
The problem is that not only the cells are not showing but the collectionview is not showing as well (I set the background to green to test it)

```
extension ProfileController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ProfileCell
            let page = pages[indexPath.item]
            print("something",page)
            cell.setImage(image: page)
            return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print (CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

"loginButton" is just a dummy image I am referencing, to appear in the Collectionview cells.

```
let cellId = "cellId"

let pages: [String] = {
    let firstPage = "loginButton"
    let secondPage = "loginButton"
    let thirdPage = "loginButton"
    return [firstPage,secondPage,thirdPage]
}()

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    return cv
}()
```

The collectionView is a subview inside from a stackview I made (not shown here for brevity) even though all the other subviews inside the stackView work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   view.addSubview(stackView)
   collectionView.register(ProfileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
```

Here is the Custom class I made for the CollectionViewCells

```
class ProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    //Integrate the page class into collectionviewcell
    var image: String?

    func setImage(image: String) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:image)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    //Here I select the image I want to use in collectionview
    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    //Setting up all views within collectionview
    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check your logged? It seems to me your have a constraints exception. Also, are you using Storyboard? If not, where is the code you are actually adding the collection

Comment: Are you using storyboard to render this collectionViewCell? If so, Please check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666495/collection-view-cell-does-not-display-image-in-image-view/37290577#37290577

Comment: I'm setting the views programmatically. Sorry, I didn't show the part where I added the collection, I edited the question so now it shows when I add the Stackview(where the collection view is in) because I took that part out for brevity purposes. All my stackview subviews show perfectly except the collectionview